# New to Python, I wrote my script in Jupyter, however it doesn't seem to work in pycharm?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

```html
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 1,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "# Installing Necessary libraries and establishing imports"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 2,
   "metadata": {
    "scrolled": true
   },
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "Requirement already satisfied: pandas_datareader in c:\\users\\l__ha\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages (0.9.0)\n",
      "Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.23 in c:\\users\\l__ha\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages (from pandas_datareader) (1.1.3)\n",
      "Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.19.0 in c:\\users\\l__ha\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages (from pandas_datareader) (2.24.0)\n",
      "Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\\users\\l__ha\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages (from pandas_datareader) (4.6.1)\n",
      "Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in c:\\users\\l__ha\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages (from pandas>=0.23->pandas_datareader) (1.19.2)\n",
      "Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\\users\\l__ha\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages (from pandas>=0.23->pandas_datareader) (2020.1)\n",
      "Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\\users\\l__ha\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages (from pandas>=0.23->pandas_datareader) (2.8.1)\n",
      "Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\\users\\l__ha\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->pandas_datareader) (2020.6.20)\n",
      "Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\\users\\l__ha\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->pandas_datareader) (2.10)\n",
      "Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\\users\\l__ha\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->pandas_datareader) (3.0.4)\n",
      "Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\\users\\l__ha\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->pandas_datareader) (1.25.11)\n",
      "Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\\users\\l__ha\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas>=0.23->pandas_datareader) (1.15.0)\n",
      "Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.\n"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "pip install pandas_datareader"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 3,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "import datetime\n",
    "import pandas as pd\n",
    "from pandas_datareader import data"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 4,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 200)\n",
    "pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)\n",
    "pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth',150)\n",
    "pd.set_option('display.width', 2000)\n",
    "pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr',True)"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 5,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "tickers =['MSFT','AAPL','GOOG','TSLA','JETS','NEE','SCHH','TDOC','VGK']"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 6,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "stockdata = data.get_quote_yahoo(tickers)"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 7,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "     language region quoteType         quoteSourceName  triggerable currency exchange                  shortName                                    longName   messageBoardId exchangeTimezoneName exchangeTimezoneShortName  gmtOffSetMilliseconds     market  esgPopulated   forwardPE  priceToBook  sourceInterval  exchangeDataDelayedBy averageAnalystRating  tradeable  postMarketChangePercent  postMarketTime  postMarketPrice  postMarketChange  regularMarketChange  regularMarketChangePercent  regularMarketTime  regularMarketPrice  regularMarketDayHigh regularMarketDayRange  regularMarketDayLow  regularMarketVolume  regularMarketPreviousClose      bid      ask  bidSize  askSize fullExchangeName financialCurrency  regularMarketOpen  averageDailyVolume3Month  averageDailyVolume10Day  fiftyTwoWeekLowChange  fiftyTwoWeekLowChangePercent   fiftyTwoWeekRange  fiftyTwoWeekHighChange  fiftyTwoWeekHighChangePercent  fiftyTwoWeekLow  fiftyTwoWeekHigh  dividendDate  earningsTimestamp  earningsTimestampStart  earningsTimestampEnd  trailingAnnualDividendRate  trailingPE  trailingAnnualDividendYield  epsTrailingTwelveMonths  epsForward  epsCurrentYear  priceEpsCurrentYear  sharesOutstanding  bookValue  fiftyDayAverage  fiftyDayAverageChange  fiftyDayAverageChangePercent  twoHundredDayAverage  twoHundredDayAverageChange  twoHundredDayAverageChangePercent     marketCap  firstTradeDateMilliseconds  priceHint marketState     displayName    price  ytdReturn  trailingThreeMonthReturns  trailingThreeMonthNavReturns\n",
      "MSFT    en-US     US    EQUITY  Nasdaq Real Time Price         True      USD      NMS      Microsoft Corporation                       Microsoft Corporation      finmb_21835     America/New_York                       EDT              -14400000  us_market         False   29.111376    13.615639              15                      0            1.6 - Buy      False                -0.053482      1621378373           242.95         -0.130005            -2.099991                   -0.856510         1621368003              243.08              246.4100        242.9 - 246.41              242.900             19285923                      245.18   242.51   243.07       10       18         NasdaqGS               USD             246.27                  29225858                 29676933              66.479996                      0.376444      176.6 - 263.19              -20.110000                      -0.076409         176.6000           263.190  1.623283e+09       1.619540e+09            1.626779e+09          1.627301e+09                       2.190   33.126194                     0.008932                    7.338        8.35            7.79            31.204107       7.531570e+09     17.853       251.060580              -7.980576                     -0.031787            231.750080                   11.329926                           0.048889  1.830774e+12                511108200000          2        POST       Microsoft   243.08        NaN                        NaN                           NaN\n",
      "AAPL    en-US     US    EQUITY  Nasdaq Real Time Price         True      USD      NMS                 Apple Inc.                                  Apple Inc.      finmb_24937     America/New_York                       EDT              -14400000  us_market         False   23.292910    30.113363              15                      0            2.0 - Buy      False                -0.152178      1621378652           124.66         -0.189995            -1.419998                   -1.124573         1621368001              124.85              126.9878     124.78 - 126.9878              124.780             59794196                      126.27   124.64   124.68        9       10         NasdaqGS               USD             126.56                 104074241                 98036200              46.597496                      0.595476    78.2525 - 145.09              -20.239998                      -0.139500          78.2525           145.090  1.620864e+09       1.619627e+09            1.627470e+09          1.627906e+09                       0.820   28.062487                     0.006494                    4.449        5.36            5.20            24.009617       1.668760e+10      4.146       129.547710              -4.697716                     -0.036262            126.811325                   -1.961327                          -0.015466  2.083447e+12                345479400000          2        POST           Apple   124.85        NaN                        NaN                           NaN\n",
      "GOOG    en-US     US    EQUITY  Nasdaq Real Time Price         True      USD      NMS              Alphabet Inc.                               Alphabet Inc.      finmb_29096     America/New_York                       EDT              -14400000  us_market         False   24.338863     6.720574              15                      0     1.5 - Strong Buy      False                -0.105057      1621378422          2301.01         -2.419922           -17.979980                   -0.774528         1621368001             2303.43             2343.1500     2303.16 - 2343.15             2303.160               840738                     2321.41  2298.00  2303.43        8       11         NasdaqGS               USD            2336.91                   1473080                  1384700             956.419900                      0.710032  1347.01 - 2452.378             -148.948000                      -0.060736        1347.0100          2452.378           NaN                NaN                     NaN                   NaN                         NaN   30.696028                          NaN                   75.040       94.64           87.53            26.315891       3.235800e+08    342.743      2284.058600              19.371338                      0.008481           1988.048000                  315.381960                           0.158639  1.532502e+12               1092922200000          2        POST        Alphabet  2303.43        NaN                        NaN                           NaN\n",
      "TSLA    en-US     US    EQUITY  Nasdaq Real Time Price         True      USD      NMS                Tesla, Inc.                                 Tesla, Inc.   finmb_27444752     America/New_York                       EDT              -14400000  us_market         False   92.459200    24.177650              15                      0           2.8 - Hold      False                -0.946575      1621378635           572.40         -5.469971             1.039978                    0.180292         1621368002              577.87              596.2500       563.38 - 596.25              563.380             36577942                      576.83   578.36   575.43       10       11         NasdaqGS               USD             568.00                  35966290                 36904516             420.870000                      2.680700       157.0 - 900.4             -322.530030                      -0.358208         157.0000           900.400           NaN       1.619467e+09            1.626779e+09          1.627301e+09                         NaN  579.028000                          NaN                    0.998        6.25            4.53           127.565120       9.633300e+08     23.901       678.758850            -100.888855                     -0.148637            673.090900                  -95.220890                          -0.141468  5.566795e+11               1277818200000          2        POST           Tesla   577.87        NaN                        NaN                           NaN\n",
      "JETS    en-US     US       ETF           Delayed Quote         True      USD      PCX       U.S. Global Jets ETF                        U.S. Global Jets ETF  finmb_281809878     America/New_York                       EDT              -14400000  us_market         False         NaN          NaN              15                      0                  NaN      False                -0.263454      1621377084            26.50         -0.070000             0.020001                    0.075331         1621368000               26.57               27.0000          26.47 - 27.0               26.470              4105122                       26.55    26.10    26.60       31       11         NYSEArca               NaN              26.68                   6220327                  5138950              13.466000                      1.027625      13.104 - 28.98               -2.410000                      -0.083161          13.1040            28.980           NaN                NaN                     NaN                   NaN                         NaN         NaN                          NaN                      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN                NaN        NaN        26.318857               0.251142                      0.009542             23.950735                    2.619265                           0.109361           NaN               1430400600000          2        POST             NaN    26.57      16.82                      21.98                         22.26\n",
      "NEE     en-US     US    EQUITY           Delayed Quote         True      USD      NYQ       NextEra Energy, Inc.                        NextEra Energy, Inc.     finmb_270586     America/New_York                       EDT              -14400000  us_market         False   26.577206     3.793556              15                      0            2.0 - Buy      False                -0.069170      1621376946            72.24         -0.050003             0.389999                    0.542419         1621368002               72.29               72.6650       71.302 - 72.665               71.302              8107720                       71.90    72.01    72.97       12        8             NYSE               USD              71.75                   8823379                  7850300              15.502502                      0.272991     56.7875 - 87.69              -15.400002                      -0.175619          56.7875            87.690  1.615766e+09       1.619008e+09            1.626957e+09          1.627303e+09                       1.435   34.260666                     0.019958                    2.110        2.72            2.52            28.686508       1.961450e+09     19.056        76.555145              -4.265144                     -0.055713             76.753380                   -4.463379                          -0.058152  1.417932e+11                 99153000000          2        POST  NextEra Energy    72.29        NaN                        NaN                           NaN\n",
      "SCHH    en-US     US       ETF  Nasdaq Real Time Price         True      USD      PCX       Schwab U.S. REIT ETF                        Schwab U.S. REIT ETF  finmb_118204473     America/New_York                       EDT              -14400000  us_market         False         NaN          NaN              15                      0                  NaN      False                 0.000000      1621370484            43.58          0.000000             0.040001                    0.091872         1621368000               43.58               43.8200         43.24 - 43.82               43.240               470426                       43.54    43.15    43.80       14        9         NYSEArca               NaN              43.51                    513453                   510866              10.760002                      0.327849        32.82 - 44.6               -1.019997                      -0.022870          32.8200            44.600           NaN                NaN                     NaN                   NaN                         NaN         NaN                          NaN                      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN                NaN        NaN        43.054573               0.525429                      0.012204             39.544190                    4.035812                           0.102058           NaN               1294929000000          2        POST             NaN    43.58      17.10                      17.17                         17.22\n",
      "TDOC    en-US     US    EQUITY  Nasdaq Real Time Price         True      USD      NYQ       Teladoc Health, Inc.                        Teladoc Health, Inc.   finmb_22548461     America/New_York                       EDT              -14400000  us_market         False -145.197920     1.359651              15                      0            2.2 - Buy      False                -0.043043      1621378307           139.33         -0.059998             2.029999                    1.477867         1621368002              139.39              143.8200        135.2 - 143.82              135.200              2908530                      137.36   139.20   140.00       10       10             NYSE               USD             138.00                   3889425                  4509500               9.649994                      0.074379      129.74 - 308.0             -168.610000                      -0.547435         129.7400           308.000           NaN       1.619626e+09            1.627384e+09          1.627906e+09                         NaN         NaN                          NaN                   -5.944       -0.96           -2.73           -51.058610       1.545260e+08    102.519       171.329150             -31.939148                     -0.186420            205.762200                  -66.372210                          -0.322568  2.153938e+10               1435671000000          2        POST  Teladoc Health   139.39        NaN                        NaN                           NaN\n",
      "VGK     en-US     US       ETF  Nasdaq Real Time Price         True      USD      PCX  Vanguard FTSEEuropean ETF  Vanguard FTSE Europe Index Fund ETF Shares   finmb_22939806     America/New_York                       EDT              -14400000  us_market         False         NaN     1.383917              15                      0                  NaN      False                 0.000000      1621372281            67.96          0.000000             0.059998                    0.088362         1621368000               67.96               68.3000          67.94 - 68.3               67.940              4373977                       67.90    67.50    68.31      280       40         NYSEArca               USD              68.27                   4176232                  7660350              22.169998                      0.484167        45.79 - 68.3               -0.340004                      -0.004978          45.7900            68.300           NaN                NaN                     NaN                   NaN                       1.578         NaN                     0.023240                      NaN         NaN             NaN                  NaN       2.820930e+08     49.107        65.948290               2.011711                      0.030504             61.802500                    6.157497                           0.099632  1.917104e+10               1110465000000          2        POST             NaN    67.96       9.15                      11.04                         10.98\n"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "print(stockdata)"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 8,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "from openpyxl import load_workbook "
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 9,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "book =load_workbook('C:/Users/l__ha/Desktop/Python/Investments Market Value/Investments Market Value.xlsx')"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 10,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stderr",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "<ipython-input-10-1ffefa2ed293>:1: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_by_name (Use wb[sheetname]).\n",
      "  mo = book.get_sheet_by_name('Market Open') #get the sheet name\n"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "mo = book.get_sheet_by_name('Market Open') #get the sheet name\n",
    " #you can set the range here \n",
    "for row in mo['A1:MF1000']:\n",
    "    for cell in row:\n",
    "        cell.value = None"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 11,
   "metadata": {
    "scrolled": true
   },
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "      trailingAnnualDividendRate  trailingPE  trailingAnnualDividendYield  priceEpsCurrentYear  sharesOutstanding  bookValue     marketCap     displayName    price\n",
      "MSFT                       2.190   33.126194                     0.008932            31.204107       7.531570e+09     17.853  1.830774e+12       Microsoft   243.08\n",
      "AAPL                       0.820   28.062487                     0.006494            24.009617       1.668760e+10      4.146  2.083447e+12           Apple   124.85\n",
      "GOOG                         NaN   30.696028                          NaN            26.315891       3.235800e+08    342.743  1.532502e+12        Alphabet  2303.43\n",
      "TSLA                         NaN  579.028000                          NaN           127.565120       9.633300e+08     23.901  5.566795e+11           Tesla   577.87\n",
      "JETS                         NaN         NaN                          NaN                  NaN                NaN        NaN           NaN             NaN    26.57\n",
      "NEE                        1.435   34.260666                     0.019958            28.686508       1.961450e+09     19.056  1.417932e+11  NextEra Energy    72.29\n",
      "SCHH                         NaN         NaN                          NaN                  NaN                NaN        NaN           NaN             NaN    43.58\n",
      "TDOC                         NaN         NaN                          NaN           -51.058610       1.545260e+08    102.519  2.153938e+10  Teladoc Health   139.39\n",
      "VGK                        1.578         NaN                     0.023240                  NaN       2.820930e+08     49.107  1.917104e+10             NaN    67.96\n"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.\n",
    "df = pd.DataFrame(stockdata)\n",
    "ds = print(df[['trailingAnnualDividendRate',  'trailingPE',  'trailingAnnualDividendYield', 'priceEpsCurrentYear',  'sharesOutstanding',  'bookValue', 'marketCap', 'displayName', 'price']])\n",
    "\n",
    "# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.\n",
    "writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Users/l__ha/Desktop/Python/Investments Market Value/Investments Market Value.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')\n",
    "writer.book = book\n",
    "\n",
    "# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.\n",
    "writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)\n",
    "df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Market Open')\n",
    "\n",
    "   \n",
    "# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.\n",
    "writer.save()"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 12,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "import time"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 13,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "time.sleep(3)"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 14,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "book =load_workbook('C:/Users/l__ha/Desktop/Python/Investments Market Value/Investments Market Value.xlsx')"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 15,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stderr",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "<ipython-input-15-da822840a9d2>:1: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_by_name (Use wb[sheetname]).\n",
      "  mc = book.get_sheet_by_name('Market Close') #get the sheet name\n"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "mc = book.get_sheet_by_name('Market Close') #get the sheet name\n",
    "\n",
    " #you can set the range here \n",
    "for row in mc['A1:MF1000']:\n",
    "    for cell in row:\n",
    "        cell.value = None"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 16,
   "metadata": {
    "scrolled": true
   },
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
  
   "source": [
    "# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.\n",
    "df = pd.DataFrame(stockdata)\n",
    "ds = print(df[['trailingAnnualDividendRate',  'trailingPE',  'trailingAnnualDividendYield', 'priceEpsCurrentYear',  'sharesOutstanding',  'bookValue', 'marketCap', 'displayName', 'price']])\n",
    "\n",
    "# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.\n",
    "writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Users/l__ha/Desktop/Python/Investments Market Value/Investments Market Value.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')\n",
    "writer.book = book\n",
    "\n",
    "# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.\n",
    "writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)\n",
    "df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Market Close')\n",
    "\n",
    "   \n",
    "# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.\n",
    "writer.save()"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 17,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
   
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "# trigger VBA MACRO to send out the email\n",
    "#Connect to existing workbook containing VBA macro\n",
    "\n",
    "import xlwings as xw\n",
    "wb = xw.Book(\"C:/Users/l__ha/Desktop/Python/Investments Market Value/Investments Market Value Email Macro.xlsm\")\n",
    "\n",
    "# Run the VBA macro named 'MacroName'\n",
    "wb.macro('CopyandEmail')()"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": []
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": []
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.8.5"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 4
}
```

I am new to python. I have nearly complete my first project however my .ipynb file was saved as a .py file but pycharms seems unable to run it.

When I run the script I get "Process finished with exit code 1". But the script does not actually do anything. Also, I got a nameerror code "true" is not defined") on my first attempt to run it in pycharms, but I used the suggested fix to fix it and it imported null.

I do not get any error messages or anything, when running the script since the import. What could be wrong?

Comment: Hi Greg. How exactly your `.ipynb` was saved as a `.py` file? Did you just rename the extensions? Would you mind to share your script if it's not too long? If it's too long, can you create a minimal and reproducible notebook that's giving the same problem and sharing to us?

Comment: Hi Enzo,
Yes, I simply changed the extension from .ipynb to .py and when I try to run it in pycharms engine I get  nameerror code "true" is not defined") on my first attempt to run it in pycharms, but I used the suggested fix to fix it and it imported null in the first line.
Now it runs but It doesn't actually do anything. Im afraid the script is too long, Is there some way I can share an attachment of it? I am going to try and attach it in .txt format to my main post.

Comment: @GregIndira yeah, that's definitely not going to work. Changing extensions doesn't actually do anything. A `ipynb` is basically a giant JSON file (that *contains* source code), it isn't valid Python source code

Comment: That's not how you convert a Jupyter Notebook file to a Python file. If you open a `.ipynb` file, you'll see that it's a JSON. Since a JSON is valid Python syntax (equilavent to lists and dictionaries), if you only rename the extension to `.py` and run it, Python will only create a JSON and exit. If you want to run the code inside a Jupyter Notebook, you'll have to copy the contents of each cell to a Python file and then run it.

Comment: @enzo JSON is *absolutly not valid Python* in general. Various things are different, e.g `true` and `false` instead of `True` and `False`, `null` instead of `None` etc. JSON is *valid Javascript* (although, I think there might be some edge-cases where it isnt').

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, you're completely right, I should've phrased it better. I was referring to the fact that OP did not receive any errors when running the fake Python file, since you can use some workaround to make it valid (such as changing `true` to `True` or setting `null = 1`, for example).

Comment: Wow, I feel like a complete moron. So simply take each line of what I typed up in jupyter and paste one by one into a pycharms blank sheet?

Comment: Yes, or see the duplicated question for an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

With PyCharm, you need to specify the script which you wish to execute before running it.

Comment: Hi Azzam,

I did specify the script. I save the .ipynb file as .py and right click run on the .py file and I got the nameerror code "true" is not defined" error message on my first attempt. 
So I used pycharms suggested fix and it imported null in the first line, now it runs but the script does nothing.

Comment: @GregIndira what do you mean "it imported null?" In any case, as explained in the comments above, you cannot simply change the extension and expect to have valid Python source code, let alone source code that replicates the functionality of your notebook. You should look up how to convert your notebook to a python file, there are various built-in ways